# Django's 'collectstatic' with Gulp

Tags: python, django, gulp, bower

I've recently adopted Gulp within my Django workflow but I am kind of stumped regarding the storage of my static files.

At the moment, I have my Django's [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) set to `E:/path/to/project/collectstatic/`. So, after I run `python src/manage.py collectstatic`; my static files are collected as intended. However, I have my `gulpfile.js` configured so that a variety of tasks are executed on the files within my `collectedstaic` directory. The output of this - which results in various minified and concatenated files - end up within a new directory, `E:/path/to/project/static/`.

Sadly, when the site's [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL) is accessed, the static files are being obtained from the `collectedstatic` directory; not the `static` directory as I would want.

Is their anyway to separate the directory in which files are collected and in which they're served? Or, does anybody have a better way for me to configure my Gulp file?

**`gulpfile.js`**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var bowerlib = require('bower-files')();
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var OPTIONS = {
  COLLECTSTATIC: {
    watch: 'src/**/static/**/*.*'
  },

  CSS: {
    src: 'collectedstatic/**/css/**/*.css',
    dest: 'static',
    watch: 'collectedstatic/**/css/**/*.css'
  },

  SCSS: {
    src: 'collectedstatic/scss/main.scss',
    dest: 'static/css',
    filename: "main.css",
    include: ['./bower_components/foundation/scss'],
    watch: 'collectedstatic/scss/**/*.scss'
  },

  BOWERJS: {
    dest: 'static/js',
    filename: "lib.js",
  },

  JS: {
    src: 'collectedstatic/**/js/**/*.js',
    dest: 'static',
    watch: 'collectedstatic/**/js/**/*.js'
  },

  COFFEE: {
    src: 'collectedstatic/coffee/**/*.coffee',
    dest: 'static/js',
    filename: "main.js",
    watch: 'collectedstatic/coffee/**/*.coffee'
  },

  GZIP: {
    threshold: '1kb',
    gzipOptions: {
      level: 9
    }
  },

  DEL: ['collectedstatic', 'static']
}

// Delete task
gulp.task('delete', function() {
  del(OPTIONS.DEL);
});

// Execute collectstatic
gulp.task('collectstatic', shell.task([
  'python src/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'
]));

// Compile our CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(OPTIONS.CSS['src'])
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gzip(OPTIONS.GZIP))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.CSS['dest']))
});

// Compile our SCSS
gulp.task('scss', function() {
  return gulp.src(OPTIONS.SCSS['src'])
    .pipe(sass().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.SCSS['dest']))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.SCSS['dest']))
    .pipe(gzip(OPTIONS.GZIP))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.SCSS['dest']))
});

// Compile Bower JavaScript
gulp.task('bowerjs', function() {
  return gulp.src(bowerlib.ext('js').files)
    .pipe(concat(OPTIONS.BOWERJS['filename']))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.BOWERJS['dest']))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gzip(OPTIONS.GZIP))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.BOWERJS['dest']))
});

// Compile our JavaScript
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(OPTIONS.JS['src'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.JS['dest']))
});

// Compile our CoffeeScript
gulp.task('coffee', function() {
  return gulp.src(OPTIONS.COFFEE['src'])
    .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat(OPTIONS.COFFEE['filename']))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(OPTIONS.COFFEE['dest']))
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['delete', 'collectstatic'], function() {
  gulp.start('css');
  gulp.start('scss');
  gulp.start('js');
  gulp.start('coffee');
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function() {
  gulp.watch(OPTIONS.COLLECTSTATIC['watch'], ['collectstatic']);
  gulp.watch(OPTIONS.CSS['watch'], ['css']);
  gulp.watch(OPTIONS.SCSS['watch'], ['scss']);
  gulp.watch(OPTIONS.JS['watch'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch(OPTIONS.COFFEE['watch'], ['coffee']);
});
```

Comment: This article suggests making a `build` directory (and I assume adding it to STATICFILES_DIRS) for development and then, when ready for production, doing a collectstatic on those files in `build` to a `static` directory: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/integrating-front-end-tools-your-django-project/

Answer (score 2):

We opted to primarily use Django Compressor due to the complexity of integrating Gulp: https://github.com/edx/ecommerce.

1. build.js gathers all of our JS dependencies into a known location.
2. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is updated to look at this location first (which can be problematic if your forget to remove this directory when developing).
3. Templates continue to reference SCSS and JS files as normal.
4. Django Compressor is responsible for (a) compiling SCSS and (b) minifying all assets. (Compressor can also compile CoffeeScript.)

We only use Gulp to to run tests and quality checks. Our calls to `collectstatic` and `compress` look like this:

`$ $(NODE_BIN)/r.js -o build.js
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -v0
$ python manage.py compress -v0`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Sadly, I am quite keen on doing this with Gulp; due to this being a 'learning' project and Gulp seems to be quite worth learning compared to the Django alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [django-gulp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-gulp/) which works with both runserver and collectstatic.